# quaternions orientation representation

Tags: ros, pose, geometry-msgs, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to understand the geometry_msgs/Pose.msg
Is there a way to non-ambiguously explain how quaternions are used to represent orientation?
I understand how quaternions represent rotation. You take some *initial orientation*, and then rotate it around vector (x,y,z) by acos(w).
However, when I'm trying to imagine orientation I can't understand what is the initial orientation. Is it set to some constant in ROS?

More specifically, if I have a orientation (w, x,y,z) in 3d to what orientation this corresponds in 2d?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9772/quaternions-orientation-representation/) by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 535 on 2011-04-19

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to make sense of a `geometry_msgs/Pose` message, you need to know the *reference coordinate system* and the *intrinsic coordinate system*. These should be clear from the context in which the `Pose` message is used. To specify the reference coordinate system, many ROS packages use the `frame_id` field of [`geometry_msgs/PoseStamped`](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) instead of using `Pose` directly.

For example, [robot_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf#Published_Topics) publishes the robot pose as `PoseStamped`, where the reference coordinate system (the fixed world frame, if you like) is `odom_combined`, and the intrinsic coordinate system of the robot is `base_link`. As the document linked to by [@dornhege](http://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) points out, the default axis orientation for a body (e.g., a robot) is "x forward, y left, z up". So the interpretation of this particular Pose message is "rotate `base_link` by the rotation given in the quaternion, relative to the `odom_combined` frame".

> More specifically, if I have a
> orientation (w, x,y,z) in 3d to what
> orientation this corresponds in 2d?

Generally: none. :-)

Ok, just being cheeky. In cases where a body can only move in 2D (like all the 2D navigation stuff), the rotation axis should be the z axis, since z is "up" (see above). Using the naming conventions from your link, that means that (n_x, n_y, n_z) = (0, 0, 1), so (x, y, z, w) = (0, 0, sin(theta/2), cos(theta/2)).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-14**:
There's another question/answer at http://answers.ros.org/question/948/what-are-quaternions-and-how-can-i-use-them with summaries of Quaternions.

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-04-21**:
Thanks, Martin, I was unsure about the reference coordinate system when I wrote my question, but couldn't quite explain it.

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-09-04**:
Hello Martin,
I have a node that gives goal.target_pose.pose.position.x and y and z and also goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.x and y and z and w. I cannot interpret these orientation values, for example, what does Orientation(0,000, 0,000, -0,260, 0,965) mean? Should these values be between 0 and 1? It would be very kind if u could help me with that!

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-09-04**:
@Yami: Please see the links from @tfoote's answer for an introduction to quaternions: http://answers.ros.org/question/948/what-are-quaternions-and-how-can-i-use-them

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-09-04**:
Thanks a world!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a pretty accessible explanation at:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/physmod/mech/gs/f13-7317.html#brcjlyu

It is a rotation of the center of gravity coordinate system.

Now I need to find what is that for PR2.

---

Originally posted by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) with karma: 535 on 2011-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on 2016-06-24**:
Link not accessible anymore.

**Comment by [ras_cal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27002/ras_cal/) on 2016-11-03**:
[mathworks link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/mech/gs/representations-of-body-orientation.html)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These should be the conventions used in ROS:
[Coordinate Systems](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6